# Run bash script from IntelliJ as root

Tags: linux, bash, intellij-idea, sudo, run-configuration

I have a bash script which needs root privileges. I run it by `sudo ./script.sh`.

I would like to create run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA, that runs this script with root privileges. It doesn't matter if it asks for password later.

Is it possible without running IDE as root or using tools like `gksudo` or `gksu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not super clear what Bash integration you use.
Probably something like the plugin: BashSupport

> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230-bashsupport

The runtime configuration window for this plugin seems not to expose permission configuration.

Hence, a simple pragmatic solution could be to actually write two scripts.

1. You keep your script as it is
2. Create a second one that calls your current one with sudo

`sudo ./myscript.sh`

[image]

Comment: This would be sufficient for my needs, but I have one issue here. I run the wrapper script, and it asks for password. Currently the password is visible as I type it, and I would like it to be masked (or invisible). Any idea on how to deal with it?
EDIT: and yes, I use this bashsupport plugin

Comment: Now I have access to a different version of IDEA with probably a different version of the plugin, but this is what happens for me. If I start IDEA from an environment where tty is present (so instead of the OS menu you start using the binary command) it actually asks for the sudo password over the command line where I started idea from (process if foreground). This nicely hides the password.

Comment: This is working for me as well, and it's sufficient by now. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, happy to hear that :)